# Custom Tkinter - Can't add Option Menu in the tabview With database Query

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a rookie in Python. I have tested Python for 5 days. And managed to create my app and have everything set up in GUI and for the database connection . I'm using Custom `TKinter`

But can't get this Right

```
    class CustomOptionMenu(customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu):
    
        def __init__(self, master, value, *options):
            print("CustomOptionMenu dropdown clicked:")
            self.var = customtkinter.StringVar(value=value)
            customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
            self.configure(font=("calibri",(10)), bg='white', width=12)
            


            # Option Menu for tablespaces
            label_tablespace = customtkinter.CTkLabel(Menu.tab("Create Datafile"),text="Tablespace:")
            label_tablespace.pack(pady=5)

            tablespaces = get_all_tablespaces()
            tablespace_value = customtkinter.StringVar(value="Select Table Space")
            options = ["Select Table Space"] + tablespaces
            option_menu = CustomOptionMenu(Menu.tab("Create Datafile"), tablespace_value, *options)
            option_menu.pack(padx=20, pady=10)



def get_all_tablespaces():     
    global conn
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    table_name = "dba_tablespaces"
    query = "SELECT tablespace_name FROM " + table_name
    cursor.execute(query)

    tablespaces = cursor.fetchall()

    if not tablespaces:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No tablespaces found")
        return

    tablespace_names = [tablespace[0] for tablespace in tablespaces]
    return tablespace_names
```

My mind is going crazy I don't know where I messed up. Can some one help me. So I can learn something from my mistake.

Old `Tkinter` seems working, but I'm not getting it right with the new custom `TKinter`.

Comment: *"Can't get this right"* - It does not clearly state what your problem is. If there is error, post the full error traceback.  Also it is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Please read customTkinter documentation for CtkOptionMenu arguments.
There is no bg='....'. It should be fg_color='....'

https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkOptionMenu